# Задать значение по умолчанию при добавлении значения

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
  $sql1="CREATE TABLE `say`(`pole` TIMESTAMP,`pole2` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'XOI')";
```

Ошибка: **BLOB/TEXT column 'pole2' can't have a default value**
Хочу чтобы по умолчанию добавлялся дефолтный текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте: [Bug #25520  Cannot create a text field with a default value in MySQL 5.0.27 for windows](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25520).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку.